# Android String contains two values

Tags: java, android, xml, string, http

I receive an XML from HTTP server as a String:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute (httpPost);
return EntityUtils.toString (httpResponse.getEntity ());
```

This String somehow appears to have two values, because when I try to log it's length I get two lines in Logcat:

```
Log.d ("XML", xml.length () + "");

17:30:22.313    19712   DEBUG   XML 161
17:30:22.313    19712   DEBUG   XML 0
```

And when I try to parse this XML with DOM parser, I get org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document.

I read about something similar [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?167941-Android-2.3.3.-JSON-bug-%28JSON-string-twice-in-responseText%29). I know it's not me who's doing something wrong when I get two Logcat lines with a single line of code. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't think that will compile as-is. Should the first closing parenthesis be there?

Comment: Maybe you receive two responses for some reason, one of which is empty?

Comment: I try to log a single String object, it doesn't matter how many responses I receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requesting XML in the same method as parsing it as opposed to passing XML String via method arguments fixed the issue. I used exactly the same code, just moved it to another method. It seems to be some weird Android or NetBeans bug.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be `xml.length` and not `xml).length`?

That would explain the logcat, but not the parsing failure...

Comment: Sorry about the confusion - I tried to log new String (xml).lenght () and didn't edit it back correctly. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

2 opening parentheses, 3 closing, as another comment said, it ain't gonna compile. Probably you misquoted the code. The second length, 0, probably comes from "". Since logcat shows two logs, you probably have a Log.d line with one ) less, and the two lines together produce that weird result.